# how to set kotlin version for gradle runtime?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

**Background Info:**

I am using jetpack compose for android developing and for some reason I CANNOT use gradle 7+. Currently I tried gradle 6.7.1 but it says

```
./gradlew -v                              

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.7.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-11-16 17:09:24 UTC
Revision:     2972ff02f3210d2ceed2f1ea880f026acfbab5c0

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.8 compiled on May 10 2020
JVM:          1.8.0_311 (Oracle Corporation 25.311-b11)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.16 x86_64
```

And jetpack compose 1.1.1 that I am using needs at least kotlin version 1.5.10.

**Wants**

**I am seeking for How to set gradle runtime version from 1.3 to the version I want.**

Accrodding to my current research, I believe upgrade the kotlin runtime-version won't cause a problem on gradle running.

Comment: I found a great article about set gradle embedded kotlin version: https://handstandsam.com/2022/04/13/using-the-kotlin-dsl-gradle-plugin-forces-kotlin-1-4-compatibility/ But this doesn't work for me since I have to use kotlin.android and kotlin.dsl will have a confict. I Alse tried to set kotlinoptions in android {} in build.gradle but it says '1.5' or '1.6' is experimental and stops the project building.

Comment: Again to friends, I CANNOT upgrade my gradle version for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to my workmate and we found answer from apg codes and verified it from google developer web.

Well, as the answer found on https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin ,I am really confused that google placed it in the library menu but not compose menu and I really did hard work to find it in compose article list. :-(

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

//just set follow options for your compose module
        kotlinCompilerVersion="1.1.0"
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.6.10"
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Update Kotlin:

```
Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin plugin updates
```

Update Gradle:

```
File -> Project Structure... -> Project -> Gradle version
```

Comment: Thanks but I cannot upgrade my gradle version for some reason and configure kotlin plugin doesn't work for me since it only updated kotlin-gradle-plugin and this is nothing todo with kotlin runtime-version ( the embedded kotlin version for gradle ).